# Getting the values of keys of Ansible JSON output

Tags: ansible, jq, jmespath, json-query

I have the following JSON data

```json
{
    "docker_compose_init_result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "services": {
            "grafana": {
                "docker-compose_grafana_1": {
                    "cmd": [],
                    "image": "grafana/grafana:8.5.14",
                    "labels": {
                        "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "4d0b5dd6e697a8fe5bf5074192770285e54da43ad32cc34ba9c56505cb709431",
                        "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                        "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                        "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/appl/docker-compose/docker-compose-init.yml",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/appl/docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.service": "grafana",
                        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
                    },
                    "networks": {
                        "docker-compose_homeserver-net": {
                            "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2",
                            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                            "aliases": [
                                "3d19f54271b2",
                                "grafana"
                            ],
                            "globalIPv6": "",
                            "globalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                            "links": null,
                            "macAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02"
                        }
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "running": true,
                        "status": "running"
                    }
                }
            },
            "node-red": {
                "docker-compose_node-red_1": {
                    "cmd": [],
                    "image": "nodered/node-red:2.2.2",
                    "labels": {
                        "authors": "Dave Conway-Jones, Nick O'Leary, James Thomas, Raymond Mouthaan",
                        "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "5610863d4b28b11645acb5651e7bab174125743dc86a265969788cc8ac782efe",
                        "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                        "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                        "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/appl/docker-compose/docker-compose-init.yml",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/appl/docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.service": "node-red",
                        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2",
                        "org.label-schema.arch": "",
                        "org.label-schema.build-date": "2022-02-18T21:01:04Z",
                        "org.label-schema.description": "Low-code programming for event-driven applications.",
                        "org.label-schema.docker.dockerfile": ".docker/Dockerfile.alpine",
                        "org.label-schema.license": "Apache-2.0",
                        "org.label-schema.name": "Node-RED",
                        "org.label-schema.url": "https://nodered.org",
                        "org.label-schema.vcs-ref": "",
                        "org.label-schema.vcs-type": "Git",
                        "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker",
                        "org.label-schema.version": "2.2.2"
                    },
                    "networks": {
                        "docker-compose_homeserver-net": {
                            "IPAddress": "172.20.0.4",
                            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                            "aliases": [
                                "fc56e973c98d",
                                "node-red"
                            ],
                            "globalIPv6": "",
                            "globalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                            "links": null,
                            "macAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04"
                        }
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "running": true,
                        "status": "running"
                    }
                }
            },
            "organizr": {
                "docker-compose_organizr_1": {
                    "cmd": [],
                    "image": "organizr/organizr:linux-amd64",
                    "labels": {
                        "base.maintainer": "christronyxyocum,Roxedus",
                        "base.s6.arch": "amd64",
                        "base.s6.rel": "2.2.0.3",
                        "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "430b338b0c0892a25522e1b641a9e3a08eedd255309b1cd275b22a3362dcac58",
                        "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                        "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                        "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/appl/docker-compose/docker-compose-init.yml",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/appl/docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.service": "organizr",
                        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2",
                        "maintainer": "christronyxyocum,Roxedus",
                        "org.label-schema.description": "Baseimage for Organizr",
                        "org.label-schema.name": "organizr/base",
                        "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                        "org.label-schema.url": "https://organizr.app/",
                        "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/organizr/docker-base",
                        "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2022-05-08_15",
                        "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/Organizr/docker-organizr/tree/master",
                        "org.opencontainers.image.title": "organizr/base",
                        "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/Organizr/docker-organizr/blob/master/README.md"
                    },
                    "networks": {
                        "docker-compose_homeserver-net": {
                            "IPAddress": "172.20.0.3",
                            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                            "aliases": [
                                "organizr",
                                "f3f61d8938fe"
                            ],
                            "globalIPv6": "",
                            "globalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                            "links": null,
                            "macAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03"
                        }
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "running": true,
                        "status": "running"
                    }
                }
            },
            "prometheus": {
                "docker-compose_prometheus_1": {
                    "cmd": [
                        "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                        "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus",
                        "--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries",
                        "--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles",
                        "--web.enable-lifecycle"
                    ],
                    "image": "prom/prometheus:v2.35.0",
                    "labels": {
                        "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "7d2ce7deba1a152ebcf4fe5494384018c514f6703b5e906aef6f2e8820733cb2",
                        "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                        "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                        "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/appl/docker-compose/docker-compose-init.yml",
                        "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/appl/docker-compose",
                        "com.docker.compose.service": "prometheus",
                        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2",
                        "maintainer": "The Prometheus Authors <prometheus-developers@googlegroups.com>"
                    },
                    "networks": {
                        "docker-compose_homeserver-net": {
                            "IPAddress": "172.20.0.5",
                            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                            "aliases": [
                                "04f346e6694f",
                                "prometheus"
                            ],
                            "globalIPv6": "",
                            "globalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                            "links": null,
                            "macAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:05"
                        }
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "running": true,
                        "status": "running"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I need an output similar to

```yaml
- docker-compose_grafana_1
- docker-compose_node-red_1
- docker-compose_organizr_1
- docker-compose_prometheus_1
```

I can do that with jq easy-peasy:

```bash
jq --raw-output '.docker_compose_init_result.services\[\] | keys | .\[\]' jsondata.json
```

But I am not able to do it with Ansible and especially `json_query` (and thus JMESPath).

I was able to get one key with

```bash
jp -f jsondata.json "keys(docker_compose_init_result.services.grafana)"
```

```json
[ 
  "docker-compose_grafana_1"
]
```

But have no idea how to get all four. Also sometimes expressions that worked with jp did not work in Ansible with `json_query`, which additionally made me mad.

If anyone can give me a solution for this (wether its with `json_query` or not) in the best case explains how it works, I would be very glad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pure JMESPath way, you query should be:

```
docker_compose_init_result.services.*.keys(@)[]
```

Where:

- `.*` is the notation for an [object project](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections), that will make you get the values under `docker_compose_init_result.services`, whatever the key might be.
- `.keys(@)` is the [`keys()`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys) function, in order to get the keys, mapped to the current node — [`@`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#current-node), which effectively means that `keys()` is going to be applied to every object which are children of `docker_compose_init_result.services.*`, (e.g.: on `docker_compose_init_result.services.grafana."docker-compose_grafana_1"`, `docker_compose_init_result.services."node-red"."docker-compose_node-red_1"`, and so on)
- `[]` is the [flatten operator](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator), in order to reduce your array of arrays to a single level array

Comment: Hey @β.εηοιτ.βε, thanks for your answer. Below is my attempt of your expression in my taks-file

`- name: debug
    debug: 
      var: docker_compose_init_result | json_query('docker_compose_init_result.services.*.keys(@)[]')`

However, it results in `ok: [homeserver] => {
    "docker_compose_init_result | json_query('docker_compose_init_result.services.*.keys(@)[]')": ""
}`

However, I appreciate the explenation

Edit: sorry for the formating

Comment: @Mangosniper well because `docker_compose_init_result` is the name of the variable, so, you don't have to have it in the query anymore => `var: docker_compose_init_result | json_query('services.*.keys(@)[]')`

Answer (score 3):

Solution using only builtin filters:

```yaml
docker_compose_list: "{{ docker_compose_init_result.services | dict2items
  | map(attribute='value') | map('dict2items')
  | flatten | map(attribute='key') }}"
```

which gives once expanded:

```json
{
    "docker_compose_list": [
        "docker-compose_grafana_1",
        "docker-compose_node-red_1",
        "docker-compose_organizr_1",
        "docker-compose_prometheus_1"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @Zeitounator, thanks. From all the answers this worked out of the box the best. However I like the approach that jq or jmespath offer and will prefer them in the future I guess

Answer (score 2):

The query below

```yaml
docker_compose_list: "{{ docker_compose_init_result|
                         json_query(_query) }}"
_query: 'services.*.keys(@)'
```

gives

```yaml
docker_compose_list:
  - - docker-compose_grafana_1
  - - docker-compose_node-red_1
  - - docker-compose_organizr_1
  - - docker-compose_prometheus_1
```

Select *first* items

```yaml
docker_compose_list: "{{ docker_compose_init_result|
                         json_query(_query)|
                         map('first')|list }}"
```

or *flatten* the list

```yaml
docker_compose_list: "{{ docker_compose_init_result|
                         json_query(_query)|
                         flatten }}"
```

both give

```yaml
docker_compose_list:
  - docker-compose_grafana_1
  - docker-compose_node-red_1
  - docker-compose_organizr_1
  - docker-compose_prometheus_1
```

---

**Note**: Be careful how you select or flatten the list. There might be a reason for the second-level keys. For example, if there are more keys in `services.grafana` the result might be

```yaml
docker_compose_list:
  - - docker-compose_grafana_1
    - docker-compose_grafana_2
    - docker-compose_grafana_3
  - - docker-compose_node-red_1
  - - docker-compose_organizr_1
  - - docker-compose_prometheus_1
```

In this case, taking the first item or flattening the list doesn't necessarily give the result you want.

Comment: Hey @vladimir-botka. Thanks, got it working with 

`
- name: debug
    debug: 
      var: docker_compose_init_result | json_query('services.*.keys(@)') | map('first')|list
`

Comment: Be careful. I added a note. You're welcome.